# Setup Heroku Database for the first time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, heroku

I am using postgresql and have been operating under my local dev environment. I deployed my app to Heroku, and now I need to setup heroku to use a database just like I have locally.

Locally, I would run this:

```
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

On heroku, I tried the same thing:

```
heroku run rake db:create
```

However, that returns this error:

```
FATAL:  permission denied for database "postgres"
DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege.

Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "username"=>"stegjyxfak", "password"=>"wB-Yfh450945jI5UrnFjxdwZ_o4N5", "port"=>5432, "database"=>"d64phj348vgdg5hm", "host"=>"ec2-107-20-191-205.compute-1.amazonaws.com"}
```

What should I be running to get my heroku DB setup? I am using Rails 4.0 if that is relative.

Comment: Have you read ["Getting Started with Rails 4.x on Heroku"](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4#migrate-your-database), especially the ["Migrate your database"](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4#migrate-your-database) part?

Comment: I have not, but I certainly will :) thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use `migrate` instead of `create`:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4#deploy-your-application-to-heroku

Answer (score 1):

Directly destructive commands (*drop* and *create*) are not permitted on heroku. But if you're ok with loosing all the data, you can reset the database with `pg:reset`.

Every other change should be done with `db:migrate`. If your migrations don't run through the full stack anymore you can also use `db:schema:load` but be aware that this can be destructive if `create_table` has set `force: true` or `force: :cascade`.